# Why is using join on array of strings causing Segmentation fault: 11 error on archiving in XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I've been spending hours trying to ding why I keep getting the segmentation fault 11 error when archiving in XCode. I've figured out (by commenting out sections of code) that using:

```
// If I comment out the second line with join, the archive works
var test = ["hello","world"]
let tested = " ".join(test)
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: works for me... outputs "hello world"

Comment: Interesting - if i move the code to another view controller, it works. it's only not working for this VC.... Why could that be?

Comment: are the statements really written on after another? if you declare another variable in between named test that might be the cause...

Comment: can't able to understand why it is not working... I tried it and it works for me...

Comment: @luk2302 - they are writting one after the other. I read a little about that error, do you think it has to do with some external library redclaring the join function?

Comment: might, I don´t know. Have not seen that before :/

Comment: I don't get it, you can build and run the app but not archive ?

Comment: @A-Live - correct. The app runs fine, builds fine. Only archiving when that error occurs. Interestingly, if I comment that .join like - it archives, without error. More interesting - I use the .join in other viewcontrollers and it works, fine. Only when used in this specific view controller.

Comment: Try to make a release build then (not commenting out this line of course), Archive normally uses settings of the Release build configuration unlike "normal" builds that use Debug configuration. If there's still an error you should be able to get more info from the build log that might be leading to settings mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the very same issue. I think it is a bug in the compiler.
The only workaround I found is to avoid to use join.

```
var array = ["hello", "world"]
var resultString = ""
for (index, string) in enumerate(array) {
    if index > 0 {
        resultString += " "
    }
    resultString += string
}
```